# Echo Dynamic ascii string in PHP

Tags: php, string, ascii

I have a dynamic value $input that represents a character in ascii. But somehow I just can't print it out correctly.

```
$str= "\155\155";
echo 'value is '.$str;

$input = 155;
$num= "\\".$input."\\".$input;
echo 'another value '.$num;
```

The first line will be "mm"
But the second line is "\155\155"
Is there some conversion I am leaving out?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. 155 is octal value to m.

Check it out:

```
$str= "\155\155";
echo 'value is '.$str;

$input = 155;
$num = octdec($input);
$num = chr($num);
echo ' another value from octal '.$num;

$input = 109;
$num = chr($input);
echo ' another value from decimal '.$num;
```

I'm not sure if you can do it straightforward. An easy way to reach what you want can be something like this:

```
$input = 155;
$num= "\\".$input."\\".$input;
$num = str_replace("\\".$input, chr(octdec($input)), $num);
echo 'another value '.$num;
```

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't clear in my question. Ideally I shouldn't print by character, I needed to print a composited  string. Is that not possible in this case?

Comment: Well.. not ideal.. we have a function that literally uses input in this form "\155\155" and it works with plain echo. For certain reasons I can't change that.  It's echo $str; and $str needs to be composited dynamically.